# Reload div fires constantly without event MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a project in Visual studio using MVC. I am trying to reload a div after a btn is clicked and data has been posted to the controller dynamically. I use an Ajax post and return a JSONresult. The code for posting looks like this:

```
<div id = "DelUser">
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Dform" }))
{
<label> Select User(s) to Delete:  </label>

@Html.ListBox("Users", ViewBag.Users as MultiSelectList,
          new { @class = "chzn-select", @style = "width:250px; height:350 px" })

}
<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" id="Button1" type="button" onclick="DeleteUsers()"> Delete Selected </button>
</div>
<script>

function DeleteUsers() {
    var myList = []
    $("#Users > option:selected").each(function () {
        myList.push($(this).val());
    });


    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: 'DeleteU',
        data: JSON.stringify(myList),
        success: function (data) {
            $('#msgbx2').html(data.msg);
//here I am trying to refresh the div after the post but it fires every second
            $('#DelUser').html('/Home/DeleteUser');

        },
        failure: function (errMsg) {
            $('#msgbx2').html(data.msg);
        }

    });

    return false;

}
```

The name of the controller is DeleteUser and the JSONresult controller is DeleteU.

I am trying to do this so that the dropdownlist updates after I delete the selected users. If there is another way to dynamically update this div, any information on that would be good to know too. Thank you in advance.

Here are the Controllers as well:

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult DeleteUser()
    {
        List<string> u = new List<string>();
        object[] users = data.getDataFrmDB("Select username From `users`;");
        if (users != null)
        {
            foreach (object[] user in users)
            {
                u.Add((string)user[0]);
            }
        }
        ViewBag.Users = new MultiSelectList(u, "Username");
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult DeleteU(List<string> Users)
    {

        bool good = false;
        if (Users != null)
        {
            foreach (string user in Users)
            {
                string ins = "DELETE FROM `xcal-server`.`users` WHERE username='"+user+"';";
                good = data.insert_update_delete_DB(ins);
                List<string> u = new List<string>();
                object[] users = data.getDataFrmDB("Select username From `users`;");
                if (users != null)
                {
                    foreach (object[] usera in users)
                    {
                        u.Add((string)usera[0]);
                    }
                }
                ViewBag.Users = new MultiSelectList(u, "Username");
                if (good == true)
                {
                    ViewBag.error = "You have successfully deleted user";
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.error = "There was an issue removing user";
                }

            }

            return Json(new { msg = "You have Successfully deleted Users " });
        }

        return Json(new { msg = "the passwords entered do not match" });
    }
```

This is just a section of my main page that has other action functions/controllers in it which is why i did not originally post the controllers

Comment: You need to show the controller method

Comment: And what is it you actually want to do? Do you just want to remove the selected options from the listbox in the success callback?

Comment: I would like to be able to post using ajax and have the multiple select list be updated on the ajax post (dynamically of course) @StephenMuecke

Comment: Updated how? - by removing the options that ate currently selected?

Comment: Yea whatever the user selects I would like to have disappear as options. without having to reload the entire page @StephenMuecke

Comment: Ok, I'll add an answer shortly, but there is so much bad/irrelevant code in your controller that makes no sense so give me 30 min or so

Comment: Yea sorry there's a MySQL Database attached which i am grabbing the list of users from and I figured if I re-made the query in the DeleteU call it might update the view.... anyway thank you!

Comment: I have added an answer for the script that will remove the options. No time  just now, but I will update the answer with the corrections you need to make in the controller code in an hour or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply update the existing listbox by removing the currently selected items. Start by removing `onclick="DeleteUsers()` from the button and use [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). Since you do not appear to have a POST method for `DeleteUser()` or a submit button, you may as well also replace `@using (Html.BeginForm(...))` with just `<form>` elements. The script will then be

```
$('#Button1').click(function () {

    var selected = $('#Users option:selected'); // store the selected users
    if (selected.length == 0) {
        return; // no point making a post
    }
    var users = [];
    $.each(selected, function (index, item) {
        users.push($(this).val());
    })
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '@Url.Action("DeleteU", "yourControllerName")', // always use Url.Action to generate your url's
        data: { users: users },
        traditional: true,
        success: function () {
            // remove the currently selected options
            selected.remove();
        }
    });
})
```

However a lot of the code in your controller does not make sense. Your adding values to `ViewBag` and even creating a `SelectList` but your not returning a view (your returning json), so all that is lost. And even if you were returning a view, your loop keeps overwriting the value of `ViewBag.error` so that only the last value would be set. Ideally, you should be calling a service to delete the users by passing the user name (or a collection of user names so that they are all deleted in a transaction). But based on you current code, you controller method can be

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DeleteU(List<string> Users)
{
    if (Users == null)
    {
        // throw an error that can be caught in the ajax error handler
    }
    List<string> deletedUsers = new List<string>();
    foreach (string user in Users)
    {
        string ins = "DELETE FROM `xcal-server`.`users` WHERE username='"+user+"';";
        if (data.insert_update_delete_DB(ins))
        {
            deletedUsers.Add(user);
        }
    }
    return Json(deletedUsers);
}
```

and then the ajax success callback

```
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
        // remove each item that was successfully deleted in the controller
        $('#Users option:contains("' + item + '")').remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: See updated answer for issues relating to your controller code

Comment: What you should also do is check if any options have actually been selected so that if none have, you do not make an unnecessary ajax call (see update to answer)

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to add a `$(document).ready(function(){});` around your script